# While loop not breaking inside a for statement

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I am attempting to write a game where a ball generates for three turns and if the ball makes it past the bottom of the screen the turn is ended.

Below is the class I have written and I can get the ball to move but when it moves past the bottom of the screen the ball does not regenerate in the middle of the screen as I would anticipate.

Apologies if this question is rudimentary but I have worked on this for a bit and seem to be stuck.

```
private void initiateBall() {
        double bx = (WIDTH / 2) - BALL_RADIUS;
        double by = (HEIGHT / 2) - BALL_RADIUS;
        GOval ball = new GOval(bx, by,BALL_RADIUS, BALL_RADIUS);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        ball.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        vx = rgen.nextDouble(1.0, 1.2);
        if (rgen.nextBoolean(0.5)) vx = -vx;
        vy = 3.0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= NTURNS; i++) {
            add (ball);
            while (ball.getY() < HEIGHT && ball.getX() < HEIGHT) {
            ball.move(vx, vy);
            pause(DELAY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need the content of `move` and `pause` methods.

Comment: Umm... You have more opening curly braces than closing in your code...

Comment: Are you missing a curly brace `}` for the while?

Comment: Also, your while loop has a wrong condition. X coordinate should be compared to WIDTH. Furthermore, the while brace does not end.

Answer (score 0):

private void initiateBall() {

```
   for (int k = 0; k < NTURNS; k ++) {
        double bx = (WIDTH / 2) - BALL_RADIUS;
        double by = (HEIGHT / 2) - BALL_RADIUS;
        GOval ball = new GOval(bx, by, BALL_RADIUS, BALL_RADIUS);
        ball.setFilled(true);
        ball.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        vx = rgen.nextDouble(1.0, 1.2);
        if (rgen.nextBoolean(0.5)){
            vx = -vx;
        }
        vy = 3.0;
       double x = bx;
       double y = by;
       add(ball, (x), y);
    while (ball.getY() < HEIGHT) {
    ball.move(vx,vy);
    pause(DELAY);
    }
  }
}
```